# convert mysql stored procedure to mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-order-by

I need to used dynamic order query in mysql and i have successfully achieved that through string concatenation in mysql as follows:

set @stmt_text := **concat**('select * from abc order by ',**sorder**);

prepare stmt_handle from @stmt_text;

execute stmt_handle;

deallocate prepare stmt_handle;

i need a similar way to convert this in mssql

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just run it like this:

```
execute ('select * from abc order by ' + @sorder);
```

But don't forget that you need to verify the sorder variable if you get it through user input (to stop sql-injections)

Comment: appreciate it!
but it would be much better if u but it this way

execute ('select * from abc order by ' + @sorder);

Comment: Yeah, that's what you get from writing it out of memory :)